# Preload Leaflet nearby tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet as my map component. When the map initially loads, I want to preload nearby tiles at the same zoom level. What is the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Leaflet Grid/Tile Layer option [`keepBuffer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#gridlayer-keepbuffer):

> When panning the map, keep this many rows and columns of tiles before unloading them.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question. The question wasnt about KeepBuffer, but preloading tiles!

Comment: Wow I really did not pay enough attention at that time, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 7):

Please note that the `keepBuffer` option of `L.GridLayer` (and `L.TileLayer`) affects how tiles are *unloaded*: A bigger value of `keepBuffer` means that the user has to pan around further away before tiles are unloaded. It does **not** affect how soon tiles are loaded.

If you want to **pre**load nearby tiles, I encourage you to look at some of the [plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tile-load), and in particular [Leaflet.EdgeBuffer](https://github.com/TolonUK/Leaflet.EdgeBuffer).